# What happens with display:initial on non CSS3 browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I need to know what value/ css would be set when I use `display: initial` on non CSS3 compliant browsers ?

I'm hiding the class using `display:none` & need to show back, for which I intend to use `display: initial` (I dont want to use `display:block` if previously it was `display:inline`) but the hidden element must be shown on all browsers.

Comment: Hopefully they'll treat it as an invalid property and just ignore it: http://jsfiddle.net/TC2pa/

Comment: @Blender: So the element would remain hidden(as they were hidden using `display:none`), no ? what about the fallback as I suggested above ?

Comment: Chrome seems to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/TC2pa/1/

Answer (score 5):

What happens by CSS 2.1 [rules on error handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors) as well as in practice is that the declaration `display: initial` is ignored, without affecting the rest of the style sheet. The `display` property thus gets its value from other rules. In the absence of *any* setting on it in any style sheet (including browser default style sheet), the initial value `inline` is used.

The “fallback” code in the edit of your question means that the value of `display` would be `inline` in browsers that support the value `inline`, and `block` in other browsers. This does not sound safe.

The value [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords) does *not* mean “the previous value set in a style sheet” or anything like that, as the question seems to postulate. Instead, it means the value that is designated as the property’s initial value in CSS specifications. For `display`, this is `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found that providing a fallback would be a safer option. So I use like below:

```
{
display: block;// just as fallback
display: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is "run-in" value for display property explained in [W3C Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

**EDIT:**
run-in value is supported by Internet Explorer, and interpret the element whether it is block-level or inline-level.

I made an example [`jsFiddle Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/gwwtpemr/) .

Comment: Please, explain your approach in the answer itself. Link-only answers are discouraged on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Of Course!
I was dealing with same issue, I wanted to hiding elements using `display:none` and want them visible back. That's painful part. I needed to use something sets element display settings as is. Using `display:initial` could not solve the problem because some elements displays overriden from block to inline-block or other display settings. Then I found `run-in` value.  It says ** Displays an element as either block or inline, depending on context** So it seems promising and what's more important is it is CSS2.1 spec and supported by IE8 IE9 etc. I went for `run-in` and it made helpful

Comment: Bu sadly today, nor Chrome, neither Firefox or Safari supported this value. So my answer obsoleted. :/