# CSS - opposite of display:none

Tags: css, hide, show

I'm trying setting up two simple css classes to toggle elements :

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.show{
  display:inherit;
}
```

It seems to work but sometimes display:inherit; return troubles so which is the exact opposite of display:none; ?

Comment: that is **Display : Block;**

Comment: All the other possible values of `display` will be opposite to `display:none` such as `display:inline-block`, `display:table`, ...

Comment: @JeyTheva why **block** if i don't want to specify it? i just need to hide and show without setting any rule :P

Comment: you can't make any assumptions about what display type was set before. it could've been `block`, it could've been `inline-block`, it could've been `table-cell` or whatever. There's one "none", but there's many "opposites" it could have been.

Comment: I guess that CSS **won't remember** the state of `display` before you set it to `none`. So there won't be any CSS solution for this.

Comment: @KingKing i dunno i actually tryed both **inherit** and **initial** they both works but i dunno differences between them and if is this a good practice

Comment: @MarcB display:initial ? dunno ...

Comment: @sbaaaang `initial` is normally the default display of the element, such as `div` has `display:block` by default, `span` has `display:inline` by default while `inherit` is the display of the parent. In fact this kind of question is very confusing. In CSS **we never encounter any issue related to this problem**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This all depends on the element you are specifying. For example `<div>` and `<p>` elements are `display:block;` by default, whereas `<span>` is `display:inline;` by default.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements) provides a list of the defaults for each element based on what browser is being used.

**EDIT**

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995816/what-happens-with-displayinitial-on-non-css3-browsers) that `display: initial;` will work in most browsers, [although not IE.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#compat-desktop) A fallback line of CSS would probably be best practice:

```
.show {
    display: block;
    display: initial;
}
```

Comment: thanks +1 actually best answer i'll wait little bit more and in case accept your ;)

Comment: `display:initial` effectively means `display:inline`, so 'display:block' can't be a fallback for it and the code after the 'Edit' is kind of misleading. There is also `display: revert` value (from CSS Cascade level 4 spec) which effectively reverts the `display` value to the browser default for the element (`block` for `div`, `table-row` for `tr`, etc.), but its browser support is even worse than for `display:initial`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Javascript to do that:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
```

And

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
```

Can toggle the display for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just toggling elements, you don't need two classes; you just need one class ("hide") that you add and remove for each element.  When you hide the element, you add class "hide" to it, and when you show the element again, you remove class "hide".

However, if you really need two classes, I've had success with something like this:

```
.show{display:"";}
```

The blank value tells the browser to ignore that property, and it goes back to its default value.

Comment: I'm interested to see your use case, but anyway, try the second option.

Comment: this doesn't works here on my site, probably you lucky :P or me unlucky :P eheh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which **element** you want to show, for **block** elements:

```
.show{
  display: block;
}
```